# connecting to mysql database c++

Tags: c++, mysql, visual-c++

I am trying to connect to mysql databse with c++.

Im not so good with c++ since i'm web developer, so i was searching around for some good tutorials and found some but most of them are outdated, and my problem that i'm using microsoft `visual c++ 2010` so most of tutorials are for older versions and doesn't work so well.

Anyways maybe any one could point me to the right direction with some documentation/tutorials, etc.

Comment: @johnathon no, at least i think so

Comment: MFC/ATL is the way to go for easy database access.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/cc896546

Comment: If you dont want to use MFC/ATL you could try to find another library for doing just that, such as http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/cpp/

Comment: If you have primarily been programming in PHP, you'll have bigger problems than this. I'd suggest starting from the beginning, because PHP is a very beginner friendly language that allows you to do stuff that would make C++ programmers cringe. It might be a long way to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try [this](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/cpp/). It seems like the most up-to-date implementation of what you're asking for. It would probably be worth getting an older version of visual C++ if need be.